# Is it possible to enable tracing in open telemetry for a specific input (such as specific user id)?

Tags: trace, open-telemetry

Open telemetry supports DST which could be triggered for all the flows, but is it also possible to trigger tracing on demand with some input value, like if we want to trace specific user transactions.

I couldnt find a way to trigger tracing for a specific user input dynamically, from the reading. looking for some guidance here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this would be to think about it in the inverse.

You can used Sampling to achieve what you're looking for, if you have access to the data at the start of the context/request.

In .NET for example, adding a Sampler that runs at the start of the request allows you to extract information from the request to make a decision. One of those might be the User Identity.

Different frameworks and languages have different ways of doing that.

The idea would be that you add a condition in the sampler that will "drop" by default and "sample" when the context has a particular UserId.